# Excel: Counting multiple characters by cell in range

Tags: excel, range, countif

I have a range as A:A since the amount of records changes. This range contains "x" in each cell which corresponds to how many projects were completed in that time. Therefore, a single cell may be entered as "x", "xxx", or "x x x". I need the number of occurrences of "x" or "X" for that matter.

My current formula is `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"x*",I:I,"Weekly*")`I have tried altering this formula but can't get the proper result as some cells contain more than one "x". Thanks.

Comment: Count the length of the string as it currently stands and then remove (`Substitute`) the target value for a blank cell and then count the length of the strength again. From there, the difference must be the number of `x`s present. **I misread your question. If you want the whole column, you can use this method as a helper column and then sum that column**

Comment: Bear in mind that substitute is case sensitive

Comment: Do these cells contain anything else, or *just* the "X"s?  (i.e. might it contain "XX: 2020-03-11" for "2 projects, completed today"?)

Comment: oh i see you use countifs, if so maybe you don't need helped column. But it does come to a solution anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUM(LEN(A:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"x",""),"X","")))
```

---

Substitute `x` & `X` with a blank value and then count & sum the difference. Depending on your version of excel, you may need to confirm formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  +  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

### Edit

A cleaner way to handle lower case and uppercase values would just be to convert the entire string to uppercase and then only replace your uppercase values (`X`)

```
=SUM(LEN(A:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"X","")))
```

Comment: This formula to work needs to be entered as array formula, isn't?

Comment: I got Excel 2007 and it does not work for me unless I enter it as Array Formula. Anyways, another fix, totally based on your formula, would be `=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A:A))-SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A:A;"x";"");"X";"")))`. This works in Excel 2007 perfectly in non-array mode. SUMPRODUCT works, but SUM does not. That's curious, to be honest. Anyways, I upvoted

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns `SUMPRODUCT` automatically treats everything inside it as an array formula, because that's what it *does* - it is the Sum of the Products of matched elements of the Arrays you pass it.  Newer versions of Excel introduced "Dynamic Arrays", where it tries to decide if you meant to type an Array Formula, and then messes it up for you - see the documentation for [`Range.Formula2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula2) for more details

Comment: @urdearboy This and Foxfire And Burns And Burns SUMPRODUCT addition are exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: If so then you should change your post: you show countifs and `Weekly`. These are 2 concurrent conditions, this distracts the respondent.

Comment: @Chronocidal Thanks for the info and link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Column A **only** contains "X"s, and no other data, then the simplest method - **if you have Office-365 or Office-2019** is to use `Concat` to turn the column into 1 giant string, then count the length:

```
=LEN(CONCAT(A:A))
```

If you **don't** have Office-365 or Office-2019, then you can't use the `Concat` function — as such, you will need to use an Array Formula to add the lengths:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A:A))
```

(Using `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUM` means that we can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> as a normal formula, and everything inside the `SUMPRODUCT` is treated as an Array Formula, instead of having to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

As BigBen has pointed out, you have said that there are sometimes spaces in there.  You have 2 ways to deal with this:  either `SUBSTUTUTE` out the Spaces, or `SUBSTITUTE` out the Xs and take the difference

```
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(A:A)," ",""))
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A:A," ","")))
'OR
=LEN(CONCAT(A:A)) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(CONCAT(A:A)),"x",""))
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1:A4))-SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1:A4),"x","")))
```

(The `LOWER` is needed, because `SUBSTITUTE` is Case Sensitive:  `=SUBSTITUTE("|XxX|","x")` gives `|XX|`, not `||`)

Answer (score 0):

i have use a helper column. Modify and try the below:

**Formula in Helper Column:**

`=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A2),"X",""))`

**Formula to get the total:**

`=SUMIF($B$2:$B$8,"Weekly*",$C$2:$C$8)`

[image]